# Putting a static address into a register with GNU AS (GAS) .intel_syntax?

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, gnu-assembler

```
.intel_syntax noprefix
.global _start
.text

_start:
mov     eax, 4
mov     ebx, 1
mov     ecx, msg
mov     edx, 15
int     0x80

mov     eax, 1
mov     ebx, 14 
int     0x80

.data
msg:
.ascii "Hello, World!\n"
```

I am trying to compile the above code via GNU AS using the following commands:

```
asad@Arcturus:~/Desktop/ZJNK$ as --32 -msyntax=intel code.S -o code.o
asad@Arcturus:~/Desktop/ZJNK$ ld -m elf_i386 code.o -o a.out
asad@Arcturus:~/Desktop/ZJNK$ ./a.out 
asad@Arcturus:~/Desktop/ZJNK$
```

But I cannot get any output on the terminal. However, the exit code is still readable:

```
asad@Arcturus:~/Desktop/ZJNK$ echo $?
14
```

I am using 64-bit Linux and am able to run the above code via nasm after required changes.

What could have gone wrong?

Comment: What is the value of `ecx` after `mov ecx, msg`?

Comment: Related: [How to load address of function or label into register in GNU Assembler](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57212012) covers x86-64.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To load the address of msg, use

```
mov ecx, offset msg
```

Comment: Thank you. I thought `offset` was a MASM thing only.

Comment: Now, do I use BYTE PTR etc as well where needed? Also where can I find a good manual on GAS's flavor of intel syntax?

Comment: @Kraken Check the [GNU as manual](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/).  If you want to use Intel syntax, I recommend you to ditch GNU as in favour of nasm.

Comment: @Kraken: GAS `.intel_syntax` is MASM-like, not NASM.  It might be documented somewhere, but most people use it as a read-only format.  (e.g. I prefer NASM syntax, and `objdump -drwC -Mintel` is very readable for me even thought it's more like MASM than NASM.  But if I was writing code for GAS instead of NASM/YASM, I'd use AT&T syntax because that's what most other projects do, e.g. glibc and the Linux kernel).